# react native: how to display the current time automatic when come inside page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to display the current time automatic when come inside page ?
i try to display the current time while i arrive into the `NetuneyDigum` page,
in my code the current time display only if i press on the `TouchableOpacity` onpress and i want to display the current time also automatic while the user arrive into the page .

```
function NetuneyDigum() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState('');
  const [isSelected, setSelection] = useState(false);
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState('1');

  return (
    <>
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#cbced4', marginBottom: 50 }}
      >
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: '#cbced4',
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              paddingTop: 30,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              paddingRight: 180,
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                flexDirection: 'row',

                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                left: 58,
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize: 18,
                  color: 'black',
                }}
              >
                current time:
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View
              style={{
                width: 150,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 2,
                left: 80,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'white',
              }}
            >
              <Text
                style={{
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: 'black',
                }}
              >
                {currentTime}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                const time = moment().format('HH:mm');
                setCurrentTime(time);
              }}
              style={{
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderColor: 'black',
                borderWidth: 2,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                backgroundColor: '#275d9f',
                left: 100,
              }}
            >
              <Icon size={40} color="white" name="time-outline" />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
// Similar to componentDidMount and componentDidUpdate:
  useEffect(() => {
    const time = moment().format('HH:mm');
    setCurrentTime(time);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this, it will come automatic. After that, you can change time display.

```js
const [startedtime, setStartedtime] = useState(new Date());
```